# Is there a way to set an action command for something that a mouse adapter has been added to?

Tags: java, mouseevent, actionlistener, mouseclick-event

If I have 5 JPanels with the same mouse adapter and I would like to determine which panel was clicked, how would I do that?

Comment: the question mark key on your keyboard is stuck ;-)

Comment: Hahaha. I didn't even know I did that. I imagine it was because I was really surprised/frustrated that I couldn't add actioncommands to mouse listener targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MouseEvent` is a subclass of `ComponentEvent`, so:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentEvent.html#getComponent%28%29

> getComponent
>
> ```
> public Component getComponent()
> ```
>
> Returns the originator of the event.
>
> Returns:
>    the Component object that originated the event, or null if the
>   object is not a Component.

Comment: Nice! I imagine I can probably use something like setName("Specific Button") or something then.